# How to make link_to links change color on hover

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get 3 of my links to change color on hover here is the css that I have

```css
a {
  color: #5c8a36;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5c8a36;
}

.home_links:hover,
.home_links:focus {
  color: #5c8a36;
}
```

```html
<%= link_to "Business Development", business_development_path, :class => 'home_links', :style => 'color: white'; %>
```

For some reason with this setup the link doesn't change on hover. I'm not sure what to do to make it work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT:
I want these specific links to appear white and then on the hover change color to the same as the rest of the links.

Comment: I believe inline styles have priority over styles defined in CSS. Remove the style attribute from your markup.

Comment: You actually **CAN** override inline styling (useful for elements dynamically generated). Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this it works for you

```
 <%= link_to "Business Development", business_development_path, :class => 'home_links', :style => 'color: white'; %>



  <style type="text/css">
         .home_links:hover{
           color:#57a22b!important;
         }
     </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either override the inline styling with an `!imporant` tag like this:

```
a.home_links:hover{
    color:#57a22b !important;
}
```

Or remove the inline style and add it to your css like this:

```
a.home_links {
  color: white;
}

a.home_links:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5c8a36;
}
a.home_links:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5c8a36;   
}
```

Or if the elements are **dynamically generated** along with the inline styling, then you can override the inline css with a selector like this:

```
a.home_links[style]:hover {
    color: #5c8a36 !important; 
}
```

---

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/125/)** using the selector override trick

Answer (score 0):

The inline style `:style => 'color: white';` takes precedence over external or internal styles. remove it for your css to take effect

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've specified both the hover, and non-hover styles to be the same colour. You'll need the hover style to be different to see the change.

Comment: I have all of the links in the website set to be that color. However, I want these links to appear white and on the hover, appear the same color as the rest of the links. I'm not sure how to achieve that

Comment: Ah, apologies,  in that case you'll want to remove the inline style that sets the default color to white, and instead specify it in the stylesheet. Inline styles will take precedence, meaning you'll never see the external style.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: red;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: hotpink;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```